# Can't update Windows 10 (x64) - PAGE FAULT IN NON-PAGED AREA

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, bsod, updates

As the title suggests, I cannot update Windows any more. It updated and ran falwlessly for 2 years before that.

When **any Windows updates are installed** (either a feature update or a cumulative update, or a .NET update - basically anything), I **restart** the PC and pretty much immediately get the **BSoD** "**PAGE FAULT IN NON-PAGED AREA**". It restarts and runs into the same error a couple more times, then finally **Windows Repair kicks in, undoes the updates** and Windows runs again without any issues (and without any updates applied).

I've been fighting this issue for a couple months now, Googling fixes whenever I get the time. This is what I've tried so far:

- Ran chkdsk /f /r - no issues
- Ran sfc /scannow - Did not find any integrity violations
- Checked the NVMe with Kingston SSD Manager - no issues, all green
- Completely disabled paging file
- Stopped all Windows Update services, renamed the folder with the updates files (SoftwareDistribution), restarted the services and redownloaded all updates
- Checked for outdated drivers warnings
- Checked for driver updates: Intel Driver & Support Assistant says "No supported driver or software updates are available for your system.", latest NVIDIA drivers installed, ASRock APP store shows no new drivers available (only new BIOS version, which enables Windows 11 compatibility).
- Tried manually downloading and installing different single updates (e.g. a comulative update, or a .NET update, or a Windows Defender update)
- Tried manually installing a new Windows version (22H2) through the official Media Creation tool
- Ran Windows Update Troubleshooter - it couldn't find a problem
- Ran Windows memory diagnostic (restarts and checks RAM) - no issues
- Physically opened the PC case and inspected the RAM
- Checked that RAM is properly detected by Windows, full capacity, dual channel and all. Windows runs extremely well otherwise, no issues, no other blue screens, no errors - nothing - so I don't have any reason to suspect there is an issue with the RAM itself

And after trying EVERY one of those suggested solution the result is the same as described above - "PAGE FAULT IN NON-PAGED AREA" BSoD, then it removes the updates and Windows runs again.

Obviously, I don't want to reinstall Windows. I just have so much software and settings for that software, that it will take me days to reconfigure everything.

Here's some info about my PC and Windows:

Windows

- Edition: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Version: 21H2
- OS build: 19044.2486
- Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0

PC

- CPU: i5-9400F
- RAM: 16GB Kingston HyperX FURY DDR4
- Motherboard: ASRock B365M Pro4
- SSD: 450GB Kingston NVMe with 100GB free space

So, **any suggestions and solutions other than what I've already tried are welcome**!
Please, help!

Thanks!

Comment: “When the latest Windows updates are installed” - Edit your question to clarify if you mean this behavior happens after a feature update is installed or if a cumulative update is installed. I won’t receive a notification if you submit a comment. It’s been longer than a few months, since your system hasn’t been updated, in over 18 months. You should know that eventually no updates for 21H2 will be released within the next few weeks if it hadn’t already happened.

Comment: You might gain some insight by running SetupDiag it’s a tool that can diagnose the reason an upgrade to a feature release  fails.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I edited the question. The issue happens for any update applied. As I stated, until a couple of months ago I updated Windows regularly, just never updated to 22H2. There were security updates and everything every month for 21H2. The first time this issue happened was actually for a comulative update for 21H2. Also, I tried SetupDiag - the log file it created was empty.

Comment: Is Windows able to [boot into safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)? Whether it does or not may at least provide some more data points to work with. (i.e. if it can boot in safe mode, the culprit would seem to be one of the devices/drivers that doesn't load with safe mode; if it does boot then it probably isn't any of the devices/drivers that is not loaded in safe mode and you can most likely consider those "safe")

Comment: Please see: [Bug Check 0x50: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x50--page-fault-in-nonpaged-area)

Answer (score 1):

Following up from my prior answer *(which was moved to a comment by someone who disagrees with my interpretation of what your question is)*:

By isolating the driver causing the problem, I've been able to work around this problem on my own flavor of this problem on my system in a *very* non-ideal way by:

1. Uninstalling the culprit driver before finalizing major Windows updates.
2. Reinstalling that driver again afterwards.

This is a pretty awful workaround long-term because it's high-overhead, but given that the problematic driver isn't being updated it's currently the best I've found in the months before and since my initial response. In my case the problem driver is an audio driver, but obviously it could be a different driver on your system. If the driver causing the problem on your system requires a restart to fully install that might also be a problem, although for whatever reason I seem to be able to successfully restart my system if it's done soon after the driver has been installed (potential lead on "proper" solution?).

(I'll also point out that my repair experience is a little different from yours, as I have to manually undo my failed updates - the repair doesn't do that automatically for me. I doubt the difference is of much relevance, but now the info is included just in case it is.)

Comment: My first though was to isolate the problematic update and never apply it. Unfortunately, it doesn't matter what update I install. It could be a .net update, a regular security update, a new driver, or a new version of Windows - any one of them causes the same issue. It's just no longer worth it to invest more time into solving it, I will simply do a fresh install soon.

Comment: @jedivader Fair enough! If you have the space to spare, you might want to consider doing a separate OS install before you wipe the original installation. That will give you a chance to install whatever you consider your "important" drivers on the fresh install. That should help you avoid the worst case scenario of doing a fresh install and the problem not actually being fixed (!). It hopefully wouldn't take too long to test either.

Answer (score 0):

**First,** get the computer manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and test all hardware.  There may be a **CPU / Motherboard hardware / Memory error** (I saw you tested Disk).

**Second:**  Trying to install Windows 10 from the Media Creation Link will kick off a Repair Install and that did not work.

**Third:**  If hardware proves to be OK, then the operating system error and/or Windows User Profile error is sufficiently serious that the most practical solution is to back everything up and reinstall Windows.

Windows Install, recover files, install Office, Adobe and several other packages and get you running can occur in one 8 to 10 hour day. I have done this.

If Diagnostic tests indicate Hardware errors, fix these and determine if that allows updates to proceed or whether the OS needs more serious help.